# SQL SERVER Views and stored Procedure issue?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a few views in SQL SERVER. I have a Final view where I've combined all the others. That's the view I want to use to populate my tblInfoTable. The thing is, I have 3 queries SOLD, BOUGHT, RETURNED where I need to filter by FROM and TO dates. For testing purposes I have hardcoded those dates when setting up the views to make sure they work. Because I'm new to SQL, I did not realize I could not pass parameters to views. But now that it's all done, I'm writing a simple stored procedure where I want to pass those two values. So here's how it goes....

```
Truncate table tbl_InfoTable <- table where I want to enter data
INSERT INTO tbl_InfoTable 
(UserID, CompanyID, CompanyName, Sold, Bought, Returned)
SELECT  
'1234',      
CompanyID, 
CompanyName, 
Sold,
Bought,
Returned
FROM vBegRollFwdCompleted <-- This is my main VIEW from which I'd be able to select everything if it wasnt for the fact that I need filtering in SOLD BOUGHT RETURNED.

Where vAdded.transDate between '12/1/2014' and '12/31/2015' <-- here's where the issue arises. I added a field in my vADDED view TransDate; where; >1/1/1995 since I needed to have it there in order to reference it. But when i write this WHERE statement it tells me that "The multi-part identifier "***vAdded.transDate" could not be bound."***
```

I'm just trying to do this for ADDED values. I have no idea what the issue might be?

Comment: your FROM references view vBegRollFwdCompleted  but your condition references vAdded??

Comment: If transDate is part of vBegRollFwdCompleted, you can filter it without vAdded

Comment: It's not though. I only use TransDate in vAdded with a filter WHERE so it doesn't appear as a field in teh VIEW. If I added TransDate it messes up the data when I pull it up.

Comment: It sounds like vAdded is one of the views that the bigger view is selecting from? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, it's actually grabbing the ADDED value. So when I had the vAdded hardcoded with specific dates, it worked fine, but now that I'm trying to pass parameters with a SP its giving me errors. I'm just starting with this stuff that's why I'm having a hard tiem with this.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the vAdded view isn't part of the query, even though it constitutes part of vBegRollFwdCompleted. You could either alter the vBegRollFwdCompleted view to include the transDate column and change your WHERE clause to reference vBegRollFwdCompleted.transDate, or you could just left-join the vAdded view back to vBegRollFwdCompleted... but at that point you're having SQL Server select from that view multiple times.